# .net core self contained and config files, what if I need to change something in config file?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Publishing a .net core application (like WPF) as a single .exe file is nice, but what if you had some config files in your applicaton? How is that supposed to work?

For example, what do I do if I have a connection string in a config file and I want to change it without compiling?

Comment: from what I understand the exe is like a zip file and it unzips it somewhere to run. Not easy to find where it unzips it though

Comment: exe file is not like a zip. It is an executable file in windows environment which has nothing to do with zip. If you want you can zip the exe file together with the config files, but this is a completely different story

Comment: You can find the actual design from docs like https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/2020/single-file/design_3_0.md You can exclude config files from bundling.

Answer (score 1):

Config files are still present in your publish folder, and you can change the value as before.

The difference you will see is that instead of having a bunch of dll files in your publish folder you have only an executable and some configuration files like appsettings.json and web.config.

You can take a look at [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables) and this [dotnetcoretutorials post](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/)

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. Using the Single File publish option, I don't get an App.config file produced. If I manually edit the csproj file and set `ExcludeFromSingleFile` on my App.config, then it gets produced separately, but when I run the app, the config file doesn't get read, presumably because the .exe gets extracted to the temp folder but the (external) config is now not included.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, looking into a way of getting the config file out of the self-contained exe and read it from outside